# Cordova Web view cache clear in android

Tags: android, cordova, caching

I am trying to clear the cache stored in android application which uses cordova webview. 
I tried with `cordovaWebView.clearCache(true);` Also tried with

```
public void deleteCache(Context context) {
        Log.i("Utility", "deleting Cache");
        try {
            File dir = context.getCacheDir();
            if (dir != null && dir.isDirectory()) {
                deleteDir(dir);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Utility", " exception in deleting cookies");
        }

    }


public static boolean deleteDir(File dir) {
        if (dir != null && dir.isDirectory()) {
            String[] children = dir.list();
            for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
                boolean success = deleteDir(new File(dir, children[i]));
                if (!success) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        } else if (dir != null && dir.isFile()) {
            dir.delete(); // delete the file INSIDE the directory
        }
        Log.i("Utility", "deleting Cache " + dir.delete());
        return true;
    }
```

But both didnt work. 
May I get any solution for this, as in web view user use to login and hence we need to clear the cache when loading the app second time.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using the "cordova-plugin-cache-clear" plugin

https://github.com/anrip/cordova-plugin-cache-clear

To use the plugin, simply call `window.CacheClear(success, error);`

and it cleans the webView cache.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest answer to this is

```
cordovaWebView.clearCache(true);
 android.webkit.CookieManager.getInstance().removeAllCookie();
```

cordovaWebView is the instance of Cordovawebview.

Use both in the event where you need to clear the cookie and cache.